# Duda sobre bucle While en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, python-requests

Estoy realizando un ejercicio probando el uso del While y creo que no lo estoy implementando adecuadamente en el siguiente código:

```
email = input("Introduce tu dirección de correo electrónico: ")

arroba = email.count('@')

while (arroba != 1 or email.rfind('@') == (len(email)-1) or email.find('@') == 0):

    print("La dirección de correo electrónico no es correcta.\nRecuerda que el e-mail no puede contener"
    "dos arrobas (@@), tampoco puede tener arroba al principio o al final de la dirección.")
    email = input("Introduce tu dirección de correo electrónico: ")


else:

    print ("La dirección de correo electrónico introducida es:", email)
```

El programa solicita introducir una dirección de correo electrónico, verifica si tiene dos @@ y también chequea si el e-mail tiene una arroba al principio o al final, indicando que la dirección introducida no es correcta.

Todo funciona si coloco de primero un email correcto (ejemplo: jacinto@yaml.org), pero si coloco un correo electrónico con dos arrobas o con una arroba al principio o al final, se queda estancado en el bucle While así ingrese un e-mail correcto (ejemplo: jacinto@yaml.org).

Agradezco todo el apoyo que puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

La falla está en que cuentas las arrobas sólo en el primer input; tienes que recalcularla después de cada input:

```
email = input("Introduce tu dirección de correo electrónico: ")
arroba = email.count('@')

while arroba != 1 or email[0] == '@' or email[-1] == '@':

    print("La dirección de correo electrónico no es correcta.\nRecuerda que el e-mail no puede contener"
    "dos arrobas (@@), tampoco puede tener arroba al principio o al final de la dirección.")
    email = input("Introduce tu dirección de correo electrónico: ")
    arroba = email.count('@')
else:
    print ("La dirección de correo electrónico introducida es:", email)
```

Si quieres preguntar por el primer caracter del email, basta con `email[0]`.

Para preguntar por el último, usa `email[-1]`.

Esto es Python, no C. No hay necesidad de contar.

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias. Ahora el programa funciona de manera correcta.
En efecto, es mucho más práctico usar email [-1] | email[0].